# Recursive time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, recursive-model

In a recursive forecasting model, let's say you are trying to predict sales for the next month and you will append that prediction to your input and predict the month after. Basically, your target is Sales quantity, which you lagged. But let's say you have other continuous numerical features like Price which you will lag as well. As your model is making predictions on `sales_qty`, it will feed it back to `sales_qty` as input so you will never run out of values for that one. So how do you deal with your other features (other than the target) in order to generate them as next months inputs in a recursive forecasting model (because eventually you will run out of them)? Do you create a sub-model and try to predict them as well?

Comment: Hi: people often use lagged dependent variable models to do that sort of thing. or check out ARDL  models in econometrics which are very related.

Comment: I used lags for both my target and my features. When I ran out of values of my target, my Y_Hat gives me that info. However, when I ran out of values for my other numerical values, I can't lag a missing value. So what should I do?

Comment: I think, as the top says, this question needs details or clarity because I'm not clear on the setup and evidently others are not either.

Comment: Please don't re-post questions that you've already asked. If you need to make a revision, use an [edit].